# Cannot assign value of type 'Array<_>' to type 'Array' Xcode 7.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors

I'm getting this error when I try to build my project from Xcode 7.0 in Xcode 7.1.

**EDIT :** I still have this error with Xcode 7.1.1, even if I comment all my code from a class where I have the error. From where could this problem come from ?? Do you have an idea ?

I have the error in 4 different classes, one of them is :

```
import UIKit

class SubInterestCell: UITableViewCell {

    private var isSelected:Bool = false

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

How is it event possible to have an error with this code ??

**EDIT :** There is no line number specified ...
[image]

I'm really stuck with this issue, and I updated my phone to iOS 9.1, I can't test my app on my device anymore except by using test flight but it is so long compare to using Xcode directly. (Because I use push notifications, so the simulator is not enough).

Is there someone who could help me ??? I'm really stuck right now.

Thank's a lot !

There is the full error before the line "Cannot assign .." :

```
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/SubInterestCell.swift
cd /Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/MapViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ShowParticipantsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/EventCollectionViewCell.swift" -primary-file "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/SubInterestCell.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/RecoveryPasswordViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/RAMAnimatedTabBarController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/SubInterestsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/BlockedUserViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/SocketMessage.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/NewUserNavigationController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/FeedsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/Event.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ExplanationViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/CompleteProfileViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ShowParticipantCell.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ChatViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/DAO_Local.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/SignUpViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/DAO_WS.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/InterestsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ProfileViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/Token.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/SettingsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/LoginViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/UTIL.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/SubInterest.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/RAMItemAnimationProtocol.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ChangeSubInterestsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/MyEventsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/Interest.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/DAO_Master.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/TabBarViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/RAMBounceAnimation.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/InviteFriendsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/UserType.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/EventMap.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/MyEventsCell.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/SwiftyJSON.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/EventViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ExistingUserViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/AppDelegate.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ChangeInterestsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/SwiftAlert.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/CreateEventViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/Reachability.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/FirstNavigationViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/Choice.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/PushSegueNoAnimation.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/City.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ChangeEventViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/API.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/Participation.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/ButtonCell.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/User.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/FirstNavigationController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/RAMRotationAnimation.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/BlockedUserTableViewCell.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/MAPFeedsViewController.swift" "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/WSingleton.swift" -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -I /Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/Benobab/Documents/FacebookSDK -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header "/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App/Comrade/Comrade-Bridging-Header.h" -module-cache-path /Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/Comrade.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/Benobab/Desktop/Comrade-iOS - App" -emit-module-doc-path /Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SubInterestCell~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name Comrade -emit-module-path /Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SubInterestCell~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SubInterestCell.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SubInterestCell.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SubInterestCell.swiftdeps -o /Users/Benobab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comrade-azxsewucksmoruaetextyzshdryc/Build/Intermediates/Comrade.build/Debug-iphoneos/Comrade.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SubInterestCell.o -embed-bitcode-marker
```

Comment: On which line is the error generated?  I assume you already tried to do `Product->Clean` and deleting derived data folder contents?

Comment: Yes I already tried, there is no line selected. I use cocoapods for some frameworks maybe it's the source of the issue but all is working fine with Xcode 7 :( (see the picture I just add on the post)

Comment: What's in your `MapViewController.swift`?

Comment: I'm sorry it's a private project but I can tell you that I'm not managing array in the MapViewController, I only get an annotation from the "self.mapView.annotations[0]", but when I comment it, I still have the error

Comment: Some googling suggests it's a bug: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20531

Comment: Yes I saw this thread but I was hopping someone would have found how to fix the bug because I can't test my app directly from Xcode anymore and it's really time consuming

Comment: The thread suggests explicit declaration of array types as a workaround.  It does not help in your case, right?

Comment: Yes I tried everything from this thread, but I really don't understand for the class specified on the question above, there is not even an array

Comment: Help, I'm still stuck :(

Comment: I would need to look at the source/reproduction myself to have a chance to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your code but try to help. Sometimes the compiler cannot detect the line of error, it's a compiler bug. In your case, it is not an error in your code. `Here is a pseudo code to fix the problem:`

If your array's declaration is like that:

```
let k: String = "king"
let q: String = "queen"
let j: String = "jack"

var card: [String] = [k, q, j]

var cardsArray = card
```

Replace `cardsArray=card` with:

```
var cardsArray: Array<String> = card
```

Comment: Good example of the foolishness of type annotations. Replace it with `var cardsArray = [Card]()`